# Llamar Ultimo ID VB.NET SQL SERVER

Tags: vb.net

Estoy desarrollando una ventana para insertar datos a sqlserver2008 desde vb.net, mi consulta es, como llamar al maximo id despues de haberlo guardado

```
Private Sub btnGuardar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnGuardar.Click
    Try
        Dim command As String = "insert into cargos (idcargo,cargodesc)values(@id,@desc)"
        executequery(command)
        MsgBox("Guardado correctamente", MsgBoxStyle.Information, AcceptButton)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
    tbId.Clear()
    tbCargoDesc.Clear()
    ULTIMOREG()
    btnNuevo.Enabled = True
    btnGuardar.Enabled = False
    btnNuevo.Focus()
End Sub
Public Sub executequery(ByVal query As String)
    Dim command As New SqlCommand(query, con)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", tbId.Text)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@desc", tbCargoDesc.Text)
    con.Open()
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: Deberias ejecutar la instruccion SELECT @@IDENTITY dentro de la misma consulta en la que haces el insert que te devuelve el ultimo id insertado y desde VB.Net ejecutarlo de la siguiente forma para capturar ese id.

Comment: Podrías editar tu pregunta e incluir la estructura de tu tabla `cargos`, asimismo, podrías decirme si tu columna `idcargo` es `IDENTITY`.

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/mqkodoldbdyzj3g/Libro1.xlsx?dl=0   

aqui les dejo para que puedan ver

Answer (score -1):

Deberias ejecutar la instruccion SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() en casao de que el campo Id sea Identity, dentro de la misma consulta en la que haces el insert que te devuelve el ultimo id insertado y desde VB.Net ejecutarlo de la siguiente forma para capturar ese id.

```
sql = "INSERT INTO...;SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()..." 
Dim id = sqlCommand.ExecuteScalar(sql)
```

Comment: Es recomendable usar `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`. Podrías revisar: [Usar SCOPE_IDENTITY en lugar de @@IDENTITY](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/dd172121(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: Es verdad es mejor usar SCOPE_IDENTITY()

Comment: En SQL Server no existe `@@SCOPE_IDENTITY()`

Comment: Además, como sabes si la tabla tiene una columna de tipo `IDENTITY`.

Comment: Muchachos, la tabla en cuestión esta compuesta por 
idcargo PK int
cargodesc  varchar (50)

Comment: El campo IdCargo es de tipo IDENTITY?

Comment: si, es de tipo identity.

Comment: Entonces te sirve la respuesta que te comente arriba!